# Is there a Simple Way to Take Screenshot in Espresso Android Studio for Every Test Case

Tags: java, android-espresso

Guys, I'm a beginner in Espresso and requesting for your valuable help, Can anyone share me the code with which I can take the screenshot for every tests which I executing ?

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow. Generally asking for code is not encouraged in stackoverflow and most likely will be closed. 

Please see [here](http://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask) to learn how to write effective questions.

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.

Answer (score 0):

I'll try to guide based on the info you provided.
First you need to to know the name of your test case.
Second i will assume that you already have granted write/read external storage
Third i'll assume you also have UI Automator dependency added.
So the implementation would be something like this:

```
    object ScreenshotUtil : TestWatcher() {
    
        lateinit var description: Description

        override fun starting(description: Description) {
            super.starting(description)
            this.description = description
        }

        fun captureScreenshot() {
           val capture = Screenshot.capture()
           capture.format = Bitmap.CompressFormat.PNG
           capture.name = description.methodName
           val processors = HashSet<ScreenCaptureProcessor>()
           processors.add(BasicScreenCaptureProcessor())
           try {
               capture.process(processors)
           } catch (e: IOException) {
               throw IllegalStateException(e)
           }
        }

   }
```

Then you could use it like this:

```
ScreenshotUtil.captureScreenshot()
```